# Given a quantum state, can you generate a uniform superposition over its computational basis vectors with nonzero amplitudes?

Tags: superposition, state-preparation, no-cloning-theorem

Given an arbitrary $|\psi\rangle=\sum_{i=0}^n\alpha_i|i\rangle$, $K=\{i\mid \alpha_i\not=0\}$, and $k=\vert K\vert$, is it possible to generate the state $\frac{1}{\sqrt k}\sum_{i\in K}|i\rangle$? I feel like this isn't allowed by no-cloning, but I haven't made progress either way.

Comment: (shifted this to a comment as the question didn't specify reliability)

Assuming "arbitrary" applies to both the state and the choice of basis (it's trivially possible if you choose a basis where |ψ⟩ is a basis state), doing this *reliably* is disallowed by the same sort of linearity argument you can use to prove the no-cloning theorem.
Assume C is an operator which performs the desired behaviour in the |0⟩,|1⟩ basis. Then, omitting normalisation factors, C(|0⟩+|1⟩)=C(|0⟩−|1⟩))=(|0⟩+|1⟩), so by linearity C|0⟩=C(|0⟩+|1⟩+|0⟩−|1⟩)=(|0⟩+|1⟩). Which contradicts the expected outcome of C|0⟩=|0⟩.

Comment: @GotCarter Thanks! You're correct that I was referring to the state being arbitrary and fixing the basis to be the computational basis. I think I may be misunderstanding. I'm not saying that I need some $C$ that acts directly on just $|\psi\rangle$. You can have however many extra qubits. Does that change anything? 

Would it change if you were given some number of copies, say $o(n)$, of $|\psi\rangle$?

Comment: @FlamtapShuckle are you asking, given some arbitrary $|\psi\rangle$, is it possible to generate an entangled state, as in can you find an operator to do so, or is there some process by which you can always create such a state, regardless of $|\psi \rangle$?

Comment: I meant the latter. I'll give you some $|\psi\rangle$ and you give me the corresponding superposition. Like, if I gave you many copies (depending on the basis vector with the smallest squared amplitude) you could just measure many times to find the correct basis vectors to make our superposition. So I was wondering if you could do it with relatively few, or even one, copy of $
|\psi\rangle$!

Comment: If $|\psi\rangle$ is a pure state on two qubits, say $\frac{35}{613}|00\rangle+\frac{612}{613}|11\rangle$, you'd want to prepare it to $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}|00\rangle+\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}|11\rangle$, right?

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant!

Comment: Are you looking for an *efficient* algorithm? If so I would very much doubt it. The square amplitude of one basis state may be arbitrarily close to $0$ but not $0$ and you want it to be diffused out among all other amplitudes. I think such a problem is at least NP-hard, if not harder…

Comment: Not necessarily, just something that works eventually. maybe the problem is easier if we assume that the minimum squared amplitude is at least some $\epsilon$?

Comment: I think I might try to solve this related, simpler problem: Given $|\psi\rangle\sum_{i\in[N]}|i\rangle|k_i\rangle$ where  $k_i\in \mathbb Z_{\ge 0}$, produce $\sum_{i}\sqrt{\frac{k_i}{K}}|i\rangle,$ where $K=\sum_i k_i$

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:** No. Assuming we only have a single copy of $|\psi\rangle$, the transformation is prohibited by linearity of quantum mechanics. That said, it can be done if we have multiple copies of $|\psi\rangle$, e.g. using state tomography followed by preparation.

### No-go result

Suppose that $\mathcal{E}:L(\mathbb{C}^2)\to L(\mathbb{C}^2)$ is a quantum operation that achieves the desired transformation. In particular,
$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal{E}(|0\rangle\langle 0|)=|0\rangle\langle 0|\quad
\mathcal{E}(|{+}\rangle\langle{+}|)=|{+}\rangle\langle{+}|\tag1\\
\mathcal{E}(|1\rangle\langle 1|)=|1\rangle\langle 1|\quad
\mathcal{E}(|{-}\rangle\langle{-}|)=|{+}\rangle\langle {+}|\tag2.
\end{align}
$$
Now, consider the action of $\mathcal{E}$ on the maximally mixed state. On one hand,
$$
\mathcal{E}\left(\frac{I}{2}\right)=\frac{\mathcal{E}(|0\rangle\langle 0|)+\mathcal{E}(|1\rangle\langle 1|)}{2}=\frac{I}{2}\tag3
$$
and on the other
$$
\mathcal{E}\left(\frac{I}{2}\right)=\frac{\mathcal{E}(|{+}\rangle\langle {+}|)+\mathcal{E}(|{-}\rangle\langle{-}|)}{2}=|{+}\rangle\langle {+}|.\tag4
$$
The contradiction means that the desired map is not linear and hence not physical.

### Pitfalls of overspecifying a linear map

In general, a linear map is uniquely determined by its action on a basis. If we specify a desired action of a linear map on a set that is strictly larger than a basis (as is done in the question and also in the no-cloning theorem), then there is a possibility that no linear map is consistent with our requirements.

Comment: I don't see how you deduce that $\mathcal{E}(|{+}\rangle\langle{+}|)=|{+}\rangle\langle{+}|$, but is it true that the requirement that all zero amplitudes remain zero already prohibits anything other than phase changes?

Comment: Set $\alpha_i=\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$. Sure, just consider action on computational basis.